# Problem: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fusedlocation

Process crashed while executing mainTest(ru.myitschool.lab23.InstrumentedTestGeo):
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:190)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:809)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:852)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:819)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:261)
at ru.myitschool.lab23.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:26)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.newActivity(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:866)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3901)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4201)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2438)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

It is my "homework" and I should to do location provider, but I have minimum 1 problem and my teacher is at
holidays(

MainActivity:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.location.Geocoder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

TextView text_longitude = findViewById(R.id.text_longitude),
        text_accuracy = findViewById(R.id.text_accuracy), text_address = findViewById(R.id.text_address);

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 }
 @SuppressLint("Range")
 public void getLoc(View v) {


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
          mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, location -> {
        if (location != null) {
            text_longitude.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            text_accuracy.setText(String.valueOf(location.getAccuracy()));
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                text_address.setText((CharSequence) geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),  location.getAccuracy(), 1));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


      }



   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
TextView text_longitude = findViewById(R.id.text_longitude);
```

You are trying to assign the variables to the widgets from the layout with `findViewById()` before actually inflating the Activity's UI.

The proper way is firstly to declare them

```
private TextView textLongitude;
private TextView textAccuracy;
private TextView textAddress;
```

and assign later in `onCreate()` after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` instruction.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLongitude = findViewById(R.id.text_longitude);
    textAccuracy = findViewById(R.id.text_accuracy);
    textAddress = findViewById(R.id.text_address);
 }
```